# Changing variable leads to referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I am experiencing by far the weirdest error I've come across right now. My code is simple:

```
wtf = 5
def update():
    print(wtf)
    wtf = 1

update()
```

With the line `# wtf = 1` commented out, all works fine, and 5 is printed. However, if I uncomment out `# wtf = 1`, before I can even print out `wtf` (5), I get an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'wtf' referenced before assignment`. I have no idea WTF is going on here. Why is this happening?

Comment: congratulations, question #25 million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there’s potential for a variable to be assigned to in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope. You can prevent that behaviour using `global` for global variables, or `nonlocal` for any non-local in Python 3:

```
wtf = 5
def update(dt):
    nonlocal wtf
    print(wtf)
    wtf = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

When all you have is `print(wtf)` in that function, Python assumes that you're just trying to print the global `wtf`. If you add in `wtf = 1`, then Python is forced to assume you're trying to change a local variable - you can't assign new values to a global variable in a function, unless you use `global wtf` at the top. So in that second case, Python assumes that `wtf` is a local, which is why the `print(wtf)` statement fails - you're now trying to print a local variable before it was assigned, or so Python thinks.

To fix this, add `global wtf` as the first line of your `update` function.